# Does the Buddha have any practices for groups and societies that would lead society to less suffering, prosperity, not decay?

Tags: right-view, sila, sangha, society, community

Actually from [another question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/41786/19889) before, but since all are part of certain communities here, good to work out seperate:

**"Does the Buddha have any practices for groups and societies that would lead society to less suffering?", or say to prosperty, not to decay.**

May the advices, as seen coming from the Sublime Buddha, elders, monk, Brahmans, Insider, are also of good for you community here and elsewhere.

(And since this all about Buddhism is a steady encouragement in practical way, a meta with metta issue, also the link to the current place of practice and reflection of yours: [2020 Community Moderator Election](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1), since where do you like to run again away and consume further without to pay as your past merits run out... and not free from desire, craving yet?)

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchanges, other world-binding trades and entertainments but for going on, going forth, escape from this wheel]*

Comment: are u voting for Drammadhatu in the election?

Comment: We don't take side especially not in communities outside, do not take part on elections of common sociaties, Brahman Element. Yet encourage to good where an opening is given, "if... then", "from arising of this, that co-arises...

Answer (score -1):

Gratitude, right view, is actually the base for the prosperity and longlast of a community, from the Buddha's teachings, instructed might know [Sangha-Vatthu](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=146.0):

> Generosity (giving into first), kind words (bearable word, swollow-able), beneficial help (not necessary desired),
> & consistency in the face of events (not bending to daily moods, trends),
> in line with what's appropriate
> in each case, each case.

Conduct, Silas, perfoming ones duties, is the place of individual contribution to a community, something actually not voluntary if part and consuming on it, as well to contribute in regard of giving to maintain. Something that contradicts modern, marxist, liberal ideas, which are cheating people for short and quick gain, grow and painful decay as result.

There is also a useful collection of parameters to be observed and possible readjusted, from the collection of [last words by the Buddha](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji_en.html):

- do the Vajjis (BSE-ler) have frequent gatherings, and are their meetings well attended?
- do the Vajjis assemble and disperse peacefully and attend to their affairs in concord?
- do the Vajjis neither enact new decrees nor abolish existing ones, but proceed in accordance with their ancient constitutions?
- do the Vajjis show respect, honor, esteem, and veneration towards their elders and think it worthwhile to listen to them?
- do the Vajjis refrain from abducting women and maidens of good families and from detaining them?
- do the Vajjis show respect, honor, esteem, and veneration towards their shrines, both those within the city and those outside it, and do not deprive them of the due offerings as given and made to them formerly?
- do the Vajjis duly protect and guard the arahats, so that those who have not come to the realm yet might do so, and those who have already come might live there in peace?

And in regard of [poorness or wealth of communities](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.255.than_en.html):

> "In every case where a family cannot hold onto its great wealth for long, it is for one or another of these four reasons. Which four? They don't look for things that are lost. They don't repair things that have gotten old. They are immoderate in consuming food and drink. They place a woman or man of no virtue or principles in the position of authority. In every case where a family cannot hold onto its great wealth for long, it is for one or another of these four reasons.
>
> "In every case where a family can hold onto its great wealth for long, it is for one or another of these four reasons. Which four? They look for things that are lost. They repair things that have gotten old. They are moderate in consuming food and drink. They place a virtuous, principled woman or man in the position of authority. In every case where a family can hold onto its great wealth for long, it is for one or another of these four reasons."

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchanges, world-binding trades and entertaining but for access a bond that leads to escape from this wheel]*